# How do I retrieve key from JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, json

Is there a way to retreive a key from JSON string with out going in to foreach loop?

```
$json ="{\"error\":{\"code\":301}}";

if (empty($json)) {
    die('empty string');
} else {
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($obj as $key => $object) {
        echo $key;
    }  
}
```

What I need is to detect where the string contains error or not, so I can create error handling.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) method:

```
$json ="{\"error\":{\"code\":301}}";


if (empty($json)) {
    die('empty string');
} else {
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    var_dump(property_exists($obj, 'error'));
}
```